# Objective-C Class Reference: Symbols not found error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reference, missing-symbols

I've been working on this iPhone app for a while now, and I had it completely finished and working. The project I was expanding on was downloaded from a subversion repository online that my professor had given me access too. I accidentally didn't download the "root" copy or something like that, so I wasn't able to commit any changes to the repository. With my instructors help, I downloaded the root copy today and added all my class files to it so I could commit the changes. However, I am now getting 3 strange errors that I have never seen before:

Undefined symbols:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_mapListViewController",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-mapListViewController
>   in mapViewController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_mapParser",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-mapParser in mapViewController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_mapTabViewController",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-mapTabViewController
>   in mapViewController.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

That is the exact error message I am getting. I have not changed any code from the version that was working completely earlier this morning. Any advice? The mapViewController file seems to be what is causing the issue, so here is that as well:

```
#import "mapViewController.h"
#import "locationDetailViewController.h"
#import "DPUAnnotation.h"
#import "mapParser.h"
#import "mapListViewController.h"
#import "mapTabViewController.h"

@implementation mapViewController
@synthesize locationManager, mapView, mapAnnotations, mParser, mapListView, tabView;

@class DPUAnnotation;

+ (CGFloat)annotationPadding;
{
    return 10.0f;
}
+ (CGFloat)calloutHeight;
{
    return 40.0f;
}

- (void)gotoLocation
{
    // start off by default at DePauw campus
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = 39.639348;
    newRegion.center.longitude = -86.861231;
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.006776;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.006291;

    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.title = @"Map";
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    mapListView = [[mapListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapListView" bundle:nil];
    tabView = [[mapTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapTabViewController" bundle:nil];

    if (mapAnnotations == nil)
    {
        self.mapAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];
    } 
    else 
    {
        [mapAnnotations removeAllObjects];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_home.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(mainpageClicked)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *mapListButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Building List" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pushMapList)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: mapListButton];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self gotoLocation];

    self.mParser = [[[mapParser alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.mParser.delegate = self;
    [self.mParser start];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [mapView release];
    [locationManager release];
    [mapAnnotations release];

    [super dealloc];
}

/*
 * Returns the User to the main Application Page
 */
- (IBAction)mainpageClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Return To Main page Clicked");
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController release];
}

- (IBAction) pushMapList
{   
    tabView = [[mapTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapTabViewController" bundle:nil];
    tabView.mapAnnotations2 = mapAnnotations;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabView animated:YES];
    [tabView release];
}

- (IBAction)addAnnotation
{   
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

    for (int i = 0; i < [mapAnnotations count]; i++)
        [mapView addAnnotation:[mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"BLAH BLAH BLAH PLEASE PRINT");
    if([mapAnnotations count] == 0)
        NSLog(@"array is empty");
}

- (void)showDetails:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [sender tag];
    DPUAnnotation *selectedObject = [mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: selectedObject.url];

    locationDetailViewController *locationDetailView;
    locationDetailView = [[locationDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapDetailView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationDetailView animated:YES];
    [locationDetailView.webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [locationDetailView release];

    [selectedObject release];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{   
    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    if([[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"Academic"])
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIImage *academicImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"academic.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = academicImage.size;
            CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding],
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding]).size;
            maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [mapViewController calloutHeight];
            if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
            if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [academicImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            NSInteger annotationValue = [self.mapAnnotations indexOfObject:annotation];
            rightButton.tag = annotationValue;
            [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return annotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }

    else if([[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"Administrative"])
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIImage *administrativeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"administrative.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = administrativeImage.size;
            CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding],
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding]).size;
            maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [mapViewController calloutHeight];
            if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
            if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [administrativeImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            NSInteger annotationValue = [self.mapAnnotations indexOfObject:annotation];
            rightButton.tag = annotationValue;
            [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return annotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }

    else if([[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"University Housing"] || [[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"Residence Halls"] || [[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"University Duplexes"] || [[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"Greek Housing"])
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIImage *housingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"housing.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = housingImage.size;
            CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding],
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding]).size;
            maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [mapViewController calloutHeight];
            if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
            if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [housingImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            NSInteger annotationValue = [self.mapAnnotations indexOfObject:annotation];
            rightButton.tag = annotationValue;
            [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return annotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }

    else if([[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"Other"])
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIImage *otherImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"other.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = otherImage.size;
            CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding],
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding]).size;
            maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [mapViewController calloutHeight];
            if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
            if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [otherImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            NSInteger annotationValue = [self.mapAnnotations indexOfObject:annotation];
            rightButton.tag = annotationValue;
            [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return annotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }

    else if([[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"Fields"])
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIImage *athleticsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"athletics.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = athleticsImage.size;
            CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding],
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding]).size;
            maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [mapViewController calloutHeight];
            if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
            if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [athleticsImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            NSInteger annotationValue = [self.mapAnnotations indexOfObject:annotation];
            rightButton.tag = annotationValue;
            [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return annotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }

    else if([[annotation subtitle] isEqualToString:@"Landmarks"])
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIImage *landmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"landmark.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = landmarkImage.size;
            CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding],
                                         [mapViewController annotationPadding]).size;
            maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [mapViewController calloutHeight];
            if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
            if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [landmarkImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            NSInteger annotationValue = [self.mapAnnotations indexOfObject:annotation];
            rightButton.tag = annotationValue;
            [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return annotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }

    return nil;
}

#pragma mark <mapParser> Implementation

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didFailWithError:(NSError *)parseError {

}

- (void)parserDidEndParsingData:(mapParser *)parser
{
    [self addAnnotation];

    tabView.mapAnnotations2 = mapAnnotations;

    self.mParser = nil;
    [mParser release];
}

- (void)parser:(mapParser *)parser didParseItem:(NSArray *)parsedItem
{
    NSLog(@"Did Parse Map Item");

    [self.mapAnnotations addObjectsFromArray:parsedItem];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {}
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {}

@end
```

Comment: check my answer I have solved this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931457/iphone-sdk-linking-errors-with-static-library/12276904#12276904)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Most likely these three classes are missing from your project file. Check the Classes group in your XCode project to see if these three files are present. If not, then right-click the Classes group, and click Add > Existing Files to add them.

If the files are added to the project, then make sure that the implementation (.m) files for these missing classes are added to compiled sources. To check that, expand the group `Targets > your application target > Compile Sources`, and see if the files are present. If not, right click on "Compile Sources", and goto `Add > Existing Files` to add them. An alternative and maybe quicker way to do the same is by selecting the .m files for each of the missing classes, and see if the bulls eye checkbox on the far right is checked. If not, then check it and it will automatically get added to Compiled Sources.

Comment: while that wasn't exactly what was wrong, you did lead me in the right direction =D. I did have the class files added already, but in the list of classes there is a target row of check boxes, and the boxes for those classes were unchecked. I didn't even know that existed until now lol...thanks for the help though!

Comment: perfect. glad you're all set to start coding :). for completeness sake  and other users who may have the same problem, i'll update this answer.

Comment: you just saved my day

Answer (score 4):

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_mapListViewController", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-mapListViewController in mapViewController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_mapParser", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-mapParser in mapViewController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_mapTabViewController", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-mapTabViewController in mapViewController.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Make sure all (mapListViewController,mapParser,mapTabViewController) have both @interface & @implementation

this solve my issue. i happen to miss look @implementation was missing

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue which I resolved by adding the Framework into xCode

Comment: I did the exact opposite and it worked for me. Not sure how Xcode is coming up with these errors... :)

Answer (score 0):

when you add CoreGraphics libraray.you need to select project_name->targets/select project name (not select project test name,its an error you face)->buildsetting->and add CoreLocation.framework

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when I was trying to have `pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig` inside app extensions. I added `$(inherited)` instead of `-ObjC` to **Other Linker Flags** in the Build Settings of the Extension target.

[image]

I hope it helps anyone out there. I have lost 1 hour finding this solution.