# Objective-C: symbols not found during link

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, sqlcipher

Very, very new at Obj-C... that said, I had some problems with code earlier, which seem to be resolved (I guess!).  Now, when I do a build, I get this:

[image: Error Message]

I am not using vanilla SQLite, but rather SQLCipher, (http://sqlcipher.net)

What symbols is it talking about?  and how do I fix it?

Thank you (in advance) for looking at this... I'm "dead in the water" until I can get this fixed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C Class Reference: Symbols not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965555/objective-c-class-reference-symbols-not-found-error)

Comment: Take the advantage of loading images here itself rather than on an external site.

Comment: Mahesh... will do... I wasn't aware I could do that... thanks...

Comment: Simon... I had the boxes checked... so that's not it... any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't added the SQLite library to your project. Choose Project->Add to Project... and select the library.

When Xcode says 'symbols not found,' it's telling you that you're using a name for something that's not defined anywhere. The specific symbol it shows you is _sqlite3_open, which looks like the sort of thing that would be defined by the SQLite library.