# Project isn't linking (KissXML/iOS)

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios, kissxml

I am having trouble linking [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/wiki/Getting) to my iOS project. I've added the path "/usr/lib/libxml2" to "Header Search Path" and "-lxml2" to "Other Linker Flags". But I get this error when building my project:

```
   Undefined symbols: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDXMLDocument", 
          referenced from: objc-class-ref-to-DDXMLDocument in RSSParser.o 
   ld: symbol(s) not found
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this thread


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931457/iphone-sdk-linking-errors-with-static-library

Answer (score 1):

You need to drag in all the KissXML related files from wherever they are on your hard drive to your project's list of files and folders within Xcode, from the sounds of it.

Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you've added it to `Project Build Settins` while it should be in the `Target Build Settings` (at least that what it was in my project).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the KissXML files show up in the `Compile Sources` section of your project's target.

[kiss-xml-files http://i.minus.com/jbyxX58Kq2a1Vx.png](http://i.minus.com/jbyxX58Kq2a1Vx.png)

Please note that i am using ARC so I have additional compiler flags for the KissXML files.